# Selecting tags in PhpStorm. I want to open tag in PhpStorm, close it and put selector inbetween (like in Sublime)

Tags: html, autocomplete, tags, phpstorm, sublimetext3

I just started using PhpStorm and can't find way to set selecting tag while writing like in Sublime.

In ST if I start typing 

`<di`

 I get list of tags and probably the first one is 

`<div>`

As I click enter, div is being selected: Sublime opens tag, closes it and puts my selector between starting and ending tag.
Unfortunately PhpStorm doesn't do so. It shows me options and let to choose some but I still need to close starting tag, write what I want and write 

`</`

to close it. I like to have start and end tag given stright away so I later won't forget to close it or so...

Comment: `div` and press `Tab` -- Emmet in action. BTW -- the way how you describe works correctly as well (inserts closing tag straight away) .. but that may depend on surrounding code.

Comment: So there is no other way to pick existing tag from list, not having to write whole name and get closing tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter `div` and hit `Tab` => you will get `<div></div>` created, with caret placed after start tag. Or, type `<di`, choose `div` from completion, then type `>` - you will get the closing tag auto-added as well (if **Insert closing tag on tag completion** is enabled in **Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys, XML/HTML**)

Comment: Hmm... yeah, but in sublime it's still much more convtenient as I don't have to type whole word (div is short but textarea is longer and I have to type it correctly or I get tag that does not exist like textera). I like typing two first letters and having everything done nicely. I'm dissapointed that there is no option doing exactly what i want :P

Comment: you can type`<te`, choose `textarea` from completion and then enter `>`; or, enter `tarea` +`Tab` to get it expanded to `<textarea name="" id="" cols="" rows=""></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so chosing/hovering over tag from the list and adding ">" is the closest from what I wanted, but there is no way to get the same behaviour as in Sublime.

Shame.

Comment: What? You must be missing something or talking about different things...

Comment: What am I missing? In Sublime I write ```<sp```, click enter and I get ```<span>*selector here*</span>```. In PhpStorm you need to add ```>``` when span is appearing on list to get it. Close, but for person who is used to clicking enter every two letters - it is a bit different

Comment: `<sp` + `Enter` ends up with `<span` so you may continue typing `class=` or whatever else that tag needs. You can always use Emmet -- it will expand into fixed tags. And you can always create custom [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) for your most often used tags.